# update child component from parent component

Tags: angular

I want to update my `ng-pagination` component from parent. I have this html"

```
<div class="search_div">
            <form (ngSubmit)="onSearch(searchval)" [formGroup]="searchval">
                <input type="text" placeholder="enter search string" formControlName="Search" class="form-control">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">search</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <ul class="search-res">
            <li *ngFor="let search of searchres.data">
                <a [routerLink]="search.Url" class="search-res-title" [innerHtml]="search.Title"></a>
                <p class="search-res-text" [innerHtml]="search.Content"></p>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ng-pagination [totalResult]="searchres.totalResult" [(ngModel)]="searchres.currentPage" [length]="searchres.length" [offset]="searchres.offset" (pageChanged)="onSubmit(searchval)"></ng-pagination>
```

and in my component I have this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sharedData = this.sharedResource.sharedComponent;

    this.searchval = new FormGroup({
        Search: new FormControl(this.sharedData.searchStr)
    });

    this.busy = this.httpCall
        .get('/pub/home/search?val=' + this.sharedData.searchStr)
        .subscribe(
        data => {
            this.searchres = <Searchres>data;
        });
}


onSearch({ value }: {
    value: Searchres
}) {
    this.sharedData.searchStr = value.Search;
    this.busy = this.httpCall
        .post('/pub/home/search1',
        {
            val: this.sharedData.searchStr
        })
        .subscribe(
        data => {
            this.searchres = <Searchres>data;
            console.log(this.searchres);
        });
}
```

So what happens. In `ngOnInit` it searches my value and passes to `ng-pagination` and it works properly. But when I search using `onSearch` it searches values properly, logs desired values but pagination component is not updating. I used debug and it didn't come there.

What can I do?

It displays this:
[image]

instead of this:
[image]

Somehow totalresult is updating and I don't know why.

In pagingation component I have these:

```
export class PaginationComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {
    @Input("totalResult") totalResult: number;
    @Input("currentPage") cPage: number;
    @Input("length") length: number;
    @Input("offset") offset: number;
    @Output("pageChanged") pageChanged = new EventEmitter();
    currentpage: number;
    pageList: Array<number> = [];
    private onChange: Function;
    private onTouched: Function;
    private lastPage: number;

    constructor(private pageChangedNgModel: NgModel, public ls: LanguageServiceService) {
        this.pageChangedNgModel.valueAccessor = this;

    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.doPaging();
    }
    ****
}
```

Comment: can you post your pagination component?

Comment: @Jai I've updated. But from search component after submiting form it isn't going to pagination component

Comment: What are the missing parts of your pagination component? In your pagination component you have `currentPage` that is not used in the template of your parent.